Why is it creted two log files with serilog in a windows service application?
I have a windows service that hosts a worker service.
But I have a log for the program.cs code and other file for the worker service code.
My code is this:
program.cs:
try
{
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);


    var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args); 
    builder.Services
        .AddSerilog(lc => lc.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration))
        .AddHostedService<Worker>()
        .InstalarServicios(builder.Configuration);

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                //.CreateBootstrapLogger()
                .CreateLogger()
                ;

    Log.Information("Aplicación iniciada.");
    var host = builder.Build();
    await host.RunAsync();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Se ha producido un error en la aplicación y se cerrará.");
}
finally
{
    Log.Information("Aplicación finalizada.");
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}

This is the worker:
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Servicio iniciado.");
        return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}

And this is the .json file:
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "./logs/log-.txt",
        "rollingInterval": "Day"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "Seq",
      "Args": { "serverUrl": "http://localhost:5341" }
    }
  ]
}

How could I have all the log in a unique file?
Thanks.

You're setting up Serilog logging twice. Once with Services.AddSerilog and once with new LoggerConfiguration(). Call UseSerilog after creating the static logger to use it in both Program.cs and any services

Thanks for the comment. UseSerilog is a method of Services, Services.UserSerilog?

The code sets up Serilog logging twice. Once with :
builder.Services
    .AddSerilog(lc => lc.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration))

and once by creating a new static logger with :
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()...

To use the static logger everywhere, use either AddSerilog or UseSerilog without additional parameters. The landing page example of the Serilog.Extensions.Hosting package shows exactly this use case:
using Serilog;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();

try
{
    Log.Information("Starting host");

    var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
    builder.Services.AddHostedService<PrintTimeService>();
    builder.Services.AddSerilog();

    var app = builder.Build();
    
    await app.RunAsync();
    return 0;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
    return 1;
}
finally
{
    await Log.CloseAndFlushAsync();
}

This is mentioned in the ILogger parameter help for the AddSerilog(IServiceCollection,ILogger,bool,providers) method :


logger: The Serilog logger; if not supplied, the static Serilog.Log will be used.


